# Dynamic 365 API only returns XML despite Request for JSON

Tags: json, api, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, http-accept-header

I am using Postman to query a Dynamics 365 Business Central (BC) API. The API is returning XML and I am trying to get it to return JSON. The [Microsoft page that gives an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-develop-connect-apps) shows the response as being in JSON format.

[image: Image from Microsoft's Getting Started Developing Connect Apps for Dynamics 365 Business Central]

I tried added my own Request header to denote that I would like JSON returned

[image]

Postman says that by adding my own "Accept" Request header it will override the one that is auto-generated

[image]

Even so I tried sending the request with the auto-generated "Accept" header disabled and enabled. This is the response ...

[image]

**Am I requesting JSON the proper way for a REST endpoint?** Microsoft's example seems to indicate that JSON can be returned yet I am only able to get XML back as shown below (just a fragment)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different endpoints you are talking about, `$metadata` which generates the whole CSDL schema in xml format, whereas `<endpoint>/companies` fetches the data in JSON format.

This can be tested in browser simply pasting these URLs.

```
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/environment name/api/v2.0/$metadata

https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/environment name/api/v2.0/companies
```

Note: Pls test it. I don’t have experience with Dynamics BC, but I managed to get these from docs with the idea of my Dynamics CRM experience :)

Comment: Perhaps it was my error assuming that the metadata endpoint would also support JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong. But microsoft dynamics uses both SOAP and Rest call, seems like you need to use Dynamics Odata APIs
You can go through this doc to understand dynamics Odata APIs :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata